# .NET core 3.1 // No se encuentra el nombre de tipo "SqlConnection" En el espacio System.Data.SqlClient

Tags: mysql, c#, visual-studio

Me sale error cuando agrego "SqlConnection" y quisiera saber el por que el error y como puedo solucionarlo

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace Universidad
{
    class conexionbd
    {
        string cadena = "Data Source= ;Initial Catalog=ProyectoTercero;Integrated Security=True";

        public  SqlConnection conectarbd = new SqlConnection();
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Este problema se debe a que la clase SqlConnection  ya no pertenece al espacio de nombre System.Data.SqlClient, ahora pertenece a Microsoft.Data.SqlClient

Basta con que agregues el siguiente using:

```
using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient;
```